# Creating instances of a type class based on runtime comparisons in Haskell

Tags: haskell, reflection, types, metaprogramming, type-constraints

Following the technique described [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection),
I've been using the `constraints` and `reflection` packages to 
create local instances of a type class `Rel` that represents (at the type level) a relation on values of type `t`.

Now I would to create instances based on comparisons of runtime values, allowing code that requires those comparisons to hold at runtime to express that requirement as a constraint where the values are represented by some kind of type-level 'variable'.  I can "sort of" accomplish this with the following code.

```
usingIf :: t -> t -- Two values of type t to compare 
           -> (forall s1 s2 . Proxy s1 -> Proxy s2 -> Rel (Var s1) (Var s2) => b) 
              -- ^ Then branch: a term with a constraint that requires 
              --   two type-level "variables" to be in a relation 'Rel'
           -> b -- Else branch: the term to evaluate if the values (of type t) are 
                --   not in the relation 
           -> b
usingIf v1 v2 ifTrue ifFalse = 
    if cmp v1 v2 then
      using (Def Rel (DVar (Proxy :: Proxy 0)) (DVar (Proxy :: Proxy 1)))
                 (ifTrue (Proxy :: Proxy 0) (Proxy :: Proxy 1))
    else 
      ifFalse
```

This code takes two `t` values, v1 and v2, and compares them. If `cmp` returns true, then an instance, `Def Rel ...`, of the type class Rel is created to represent the fact that these values are in the relation, where v1 and v2 are represented at the type level by two variables with id 0 and 1.

This code compiles and runs as I would expect (in my project), but the problem is that the ids of the variables will not be unique if multiple `usingIf` applications are composed.  What I really need is, for instance, a way of tracking how many instances have been added to the Rel dictionary or something equivalent to that so that I can create fresh ids for each Var.

Any suggestions on how I could tackle this problem? I'd prefer not to use Template Haskell, but am willing to if that's the only/cleanest option.

Comment: Are you willing to have `usingIF` return a different type? Perhaps instead of working with *any* `b` it can only work with your expression type, and then you add a class constraint like `.. (forall s1 s2 . NotOccurs '[ s1, s2 ] r) => Proxy s1 -> Proxy s2 -> Rel (Var s1) (Var s2) => r) ..` - then the `NotOccurs` class takes care of name supply by taking an existing expression and computing free names for that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible trick is to hook in to the generativity that already exists in the type system.

The following function is ill-typed:

```
f :: a -> b -> a
f x y = x `asTypeOf` y
```

Even though `b` might actually be the same as `a` in some instantiation, since it also may not, `a` and `b` are treated as different types.  Particularly for higher rank types, the way this is implemented is that the compiler makes up a type on the fly for each quantified type variable, so `x :: Fresh_a` and `y :: Fresh_b`.  These `Fresh_a`s are the "rigid" variables the compiler complains about.  Essentially, the dual thing happens when opening an existential.  In fact, I'll use an existential since it seems a bit clearer and more explicit.

```
-- Needs ExistentialQuantification and PolyKinds, but the same effect
-- could be accomplished without either.
data Gen = forall (n :: k). Gen (Proxy n)
gen = Gen Proxy -- Probably need to turn off the monomorphism restriction

usingIf :: t -> t
        -> (forall s1 s2 . Proxy s1 -> Proxy s2 -> Rel (Var s1) (Var s2) => b)
        -> b 
        -> b
usingIf v1 v2 ifTrue ifFalse = 
    if cmp v1 v2 then
      case gen of Gen p -> -- the compiler has forgotten what went in to gen so it must
          case gen of Gen q -> -- assume p and q have types distinct from everything
              using (Def Rel (DVar p) (DVar q)) (ifTrue p q)
    else 
      ifFalse
```

I don't have your code so I have no idea if this will actually work for you, but it is how I would start attacking it.  You may need to massage it a little.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! I ended up trying something sort of similar to this, actually. Opening an existential did seem to do the trick.  To preserve the association between v1 and p etc, I ended up refactoring so that I'm passing around a pair with a value and a singleton type (instead of a Proxy).  This lets me move easily between the static and dynamic world and build up more complex relationships between the type variables.